# Add multiple real-time plots on the same page with Chart.js (Django)

Tags: django, websocket, chart.js, real-time-data

i'm trying to add multiple real-time plots on the same page (Django framework) with Chart.js using websockets. When i try to add separate socket on the 2nd plot, the 1st  freezes. Here is my code, thanks a lot. I'm sure there is a better way to write code, but I'm relatively new to js.

```
  <script>
        let socket =new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/polData/');
            socket.onopen =function(e){
                alert('Connection established');
            };

            socket.onmessage = function(e){
                console.log(e.data);
                var recData=JSON.parse(e.data);
                dataObjNew=dataObj['data']['datasets'][0]['data'];
                dataObjNew.shift();
                dataObjNew.push(recData.value);
                dataObj['data']['datasets'][0]['data']=dataObjNew;
                window.myLine.update();
            };

            socket.onclose = function(e){
                alert('Connection CLosed');
            };
            
    </script>
                      
<script>
         var dataObj={
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Real time data',
                    borderColor: "#1d7af3",
                    pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#1d7af3",
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointHoverRadius: 4,
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointRadius: 4,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    fill: true,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true, 
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                labels : {
                    padding: 10,
                    fontColor: '#1d7af3',
                }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    bodySpacing: 4,
                    mode:"nearest",
                    intersect: 0,
                    position:"nearest",
                    xPadding:10,
                    yPadding:10,
                    caretPadding:10
                },
                layout:{
                    padding:{left:15,right:15,top:15,bottom:15}
            },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
            

    var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx,dataObj );

</script>
```

```
<script>

    let socket =new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/polData2/');
        socket.onopen =function(e){
            alert('Connection established');
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(e){
            console.log(e.data);
            var recData=JSON.parse(e.data);
            dataObjNew2=dataObj2['data']['datasets'][0]['data'];
            dataObjNew2.shift();
            dataObjNew2.push(recData.value);
            dataObj2['data']['datasets'][0]['data']=dataObjNew2;
            window.myLine.update();
        };

        socket.onclose = function(e){
            alert('Connection CLosed');
        };
        
</script>
        
<script>
    var dataObj2={
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Sales",
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(23, 125, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(23, 125, 255)',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                }]
            },
            options: {
            responsive: true, 
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    }
        

var ctx2 = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2,dataObj2 );

</script>
```

*polData is just random values from a script*